# How can I use flavors to set different endpoints to my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, endpoint, android-productflavors

I've an app and I want to have an English version too (It's only in Spanish now). I've already created all the strings and resources, and I want to use them and set different endpoints to my app whether it's the english version or the spanish one. How can I do that?

I know I could use flavors but I've never read about setting different endpoints with flavors, is it possible to use flavors or do I have to use something else?

P.S.: By "endpoints" I mean servers that answer http REST requests

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "endpoints" here? That term has multiple uses.

Comment: By "endpoints" I mean servers that answer http REST requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you would have 2 different folders **values** and **values-es**. The best way for you is to create **config.xml** file in both folders with different url e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="endpoint">http://endpoint.com/en/index.html</string>
</resources>
```

To get the value for particular language you would get it like ordinary string:

```
context.getString(R.string.endpoint);
```

Comment: So I should use it simply as a string and that's it? Is that easy?

Comment: @Nahue yes, my point is that should not be in string.xml, because the purpose is lil bit different, but yes it is easy one :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try it and I'll make you know if it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Flavours is not what you want to use because then you will build different APK file.

You probably want to have a unique app with different languages capability.
The Android doc has a great explanation about how to do this : 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't support different endpoints like I want, it's just language support

Comment: Well in the various String ressources, you could save different endpoints URL according to the country

Comment: That's what Viktor Yakunin said but does it really work?

Comment: I'm gonna try it now!